# Is there a media player that maintains watched / unwatched / progress status for video files?

Tags: video, multimedia, media

For example, if I have a TV show series with files for episodes S01E01 through S01E10, I'd like to be able to see what I have watched, what I have not watched, and for anything partially watched be able to see how many minutes / seconds of progress and start watching the video again from that position.

Comment: Which Ubuntu release are you running?

Comment: `vlc` has a recently-used list showing what you've watched, and when you select one offers to 'resume where you left off'.  It's available for all supported releases of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Mitch Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: you can use the `bookmark` feature of `vlc` - or go give a try to `kodi` for more featured user experience